# Using EXCEPT and DISTINCT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out if any users in this table have multiple email addresses.

When I run the following two queries, the non-DISTINCT query has more results than the one using DISTINCT.

```
SELECT UserName, EmailAddress 
FROM Users;

SELECT DISTINCT UserName, EmailAddress 
FROM Users;
```

However, this query does not return any results (presumably since the remaining rows would be identical to one which is in both tables).

```
SELECT UserName, Payment 
FROM Users

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT UserName, Payment 
FROM Users
```

How can I get the users with multiple email addresses?

Comment: what sql system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use aggregation.  If you want the list:

```
SELECT UserName, EmailAddress
FROM Users
GROUP BY UserName, EmailAddress
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you just want a count of duplicates, you can count the difference.  Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't allow multiple columns for `COUNT(DISTINCT)` but you can concatenate them.  Assuming neither value is ever `NULL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT UserName + ' ' + EmailAddress) as numDuplicates
FROM Users;
```